# Multiple select list on same page -> error

Tags: php, html, joomla

i'm going crazy trying to solve a VERY weird error in a PHP script (Joomla). I have a page that displays multiple select dropdown lists, all of them showing the same list of items (the selected item changes from one list to another, but listed items are the same). This list has around 35-40 items. This works fine until a certain amount of selects, but when i put more than 20 or 25 selects on the same page, it doesn't work and shows only a white page. No errors, there is no text displayed, no errors in php logs, nothing; just a white page. If using THE SAME CODE, i display 11 dropdown select lists... it works.

I'm guessing that this problem is related to memory or something like that, but i can't be sure cause as i've said, there is no errors displayed. Does anyone knows about a simmilar issues? can anyone give me a tip about how to address this problem? i don't know what to do and i've tried many things but it still doesn't work. Any help will be very much appreciated and wellcomed...

NOTE: The select list are filled with values from a DB table and each select list has a different selected item based on contents from another table. It's not a very complex code and as i've said, it works fine when i use less select lists on the same page. The problem is when i reach a certain number of select lists on the same page (i think that it's around 20 or 25 input selects). I think that the amount of data is not very exagerated, so i can't understand why it doesn't work¿!?

Comment: Did you have a look in the delivered source code (Ctrl+U in Firefox) in the case when no selects are displayed?

Comment: yes, the source code is empty

Comment: If you have access you could check the web server's (Apache?) log files, see what requests are being handled, etc.

Comment: i've checked the apache log files, there is no errors...

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for your issue turns [this](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2233203&sid=5a6bd4c88aaea8c8d89aeb47ac96117d#p2233203) up:

> for jos_session, which is the only table I suggested you empty, any logged on users will be logged off...any work in progress (forum posts/articles would be lost)...
>
> I also empty recaptcha...
>
> Please remember to always back up your db first.
>
> ### I empty these two for a higher volume joomla 1.5 system once a week...we also set the session lifetime (no activity) varies 60-90 minutes...6-7k day volume site...this also helps our akeeba back up, as the two aforementioned tables can get very large without proper maintenance.
>
> Just some general ramblings...
>
> You should also review your mysql site report via phymyadmin "Show MySQL runtime information". Look for things that are in 'red'.
>
> As for your overall question about performance. Please remember that there are many ways to improve websites performance. It's yes another job required by site administrators and at least an interesting process.
>
> The joomla performance forum is a great place to have your site reviewed and get good help tuning your site including the minimum base server you need (shared/vps/dedicicated).
>
> IMHO...First objective is to turn off joomla cache and joomla gzip by enabling standard server modules like mod_deflate and mod_expires (mod_expires is one of the best fixes for returning visitors). Make sure you mysql configuration enabling query_cache are or can be set. You will need a minimum of a vps. and there's more!...jajajaja
>
> A little note about running shared server, and not having certain server modules available, 
>   check this out: http://www.webogroup.com/ It's really one heck of a product. I've used it on the aforementioned site until I could implement the changes on the server. As I implemented each new server module I turned off the webo...site is now boring fast
>
> have fun

Comment: yes, i've turned on the display errors feature in my php.ini, but it doesn't display anything!

Comment: soory, i've been looking into the wrong apache log file, now i've displayed the right one and i can see a generic error: "mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds" and "premature end of script headers"

Comment: i can't see how is this related to my problem. If you read carefully my question, you will notice that the script works fine if i limit the generated amount of drop down list on the same page. Also, i've now did a quick test, limiting the amount of displayed characters for each  dropdown item text, and this way it works also!

Comment: Your site is bogged down due to the awful way that joomla stores it's data, this will likely give you more breathing room.

Comment: i've emptied my session table anyway, but this doesn't solves anything. The site is working fine, the problem is only with one php script.